# Can two tabs have different CTAs?

Tags: lists, input-fields, tabs, cta

we have this case where we have two tabs and under one , we have option to show save and cancel and not in other. If I use save cancel for second tab too, then view number 3 looks absurd with two ctas next to each other

First Tab

[image: First tab]

Second Tab

[image]

When you click on one member, it opens a panel that slides from right and
we have save in that panel.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes because **you're mixing READING and EDITING screens**. If you're editing, you need to make it very clear. Your [*action buttons*](https://uxplanet.org/button-ux-design-best-practices-types-and-states-647cf4ae0fc6) (please do not confuse with [*CTA*](https://uxdesign.cc/7-cta-button-design-guidelines-4cdc21c2c85a)) make sense on an edition page, but of course, they're not needed if the user is viewing data.

This is why you're facing this problem: **in one screen you have nothing to save, because you're mixing different types of views.**

As for your most general question, tabs *MAY* have different CTAs, as long as they hold completely different content. This is more common on mobile, and quite unusual on desktop. You may think of them as just carousels with CTAs if you want.

However, in your specific case, **you don't have CTAs**. In this case, **you shouldn't use action buttons on one tab and nothing on another**. As a matter of fact, *you shouldn't use tabs at all*! Tabs hide snippets of information from the user, so you'll end with incomplete journeys and/or lots of errors

From [**Tabs, user right**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tabs-used-right/):

> Use tabs only when users don't need to see content from multiple tabs
>   simultaneously. If people do need to compare the info behind different
>   tabs, then having to switch back and forth puts an added burden on
>   their short-term memory, increases cognitive load and interaction
>   cost, and lowers usability compared to a design that puts everything
>   on one big page.

Of course, there are many way to do what you want to do in a more seamless way, but that's another question.

Comment: Hi Devin,Thanks for the good answer. If i don't use Tabs, user will have to scroll way down to see List of Users and that list can be long and isn't discoverable.  Your right about the View vs Edit mode, I am also trying a way to way to solve this.